# Laravel app using Symfony to execute a Python script on LEMP stack - Permission denied

Tags: python, linux, laravel, symfony, nginx

I have just uploaded my laravel app to the web using Digital Ocean (LEMP stack), however when I try to run a python process I am getting permission denied. This worked on local with no permission issues.

I have tried giving access to the Find/process.py file and folder with the following but no progress:

> ```
> sudo find /var/www/sync/Find/*.py -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
> sudo find /var/www/sync/Find/*.py -exec chmod 644 {} \;
> sudo find /var/www/sync/Find/*.py -type d -exec chmod u+x {} \;
> ```

```
Error Output:
================
sh: 1: /usr/lib/python3.5: Permission denied
 {"userId":1,"email":"admin@admin.com","exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Exception\\ProcessFailedException(code: 0): The command \"/usr/lib/python3.5 Find/process.py\" failed.

Exit Code: 126(Invoked command cannot execute)

Working directory: /var/www/sync

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
sh: 1: /usr/lib/python3.5: Permission denied
 at /var/www/sync/App/Find/process.php:51)
```

I do not believe it to be the php file as it works local and the error clearly says permission denied however I am not sure how else to troubleshoot this and any help is useful. Thanks

Comment: Can you `which python` and/or `whereis python`.  Also the php-fpm user that needs to run python may not have the rights to execute it.   Seems like a permissions issue.

Comment: # which python3
/usr/bin/python3
# whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3.5m /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3.5 /usr/lib/python3 /etc/python3.5 /etc/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.5 /usr/share/python3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the python bin path from "/usr/lib/python3.5" to just "python3.5" and its now working.